# how to show/hide of specific folder images?

Tags: jquery

I have the following html produced by a slider plugin....

```
<div id="someid">
<img src="/mysite/images/one/img-1.jpg" />
<img src="/mysite/images/one/img-2.jpg" />
<img src="/mysite/images/one/img-3.jpg" />
<img src="/mysite/images/one/img-4.jpg" />

<img src="/mysite/images/two/img-1.jpg" />
<img src="/mysite/images/two/img-2.jpg" />
<img src="/mysite/images/two/img-3.jpg" />
<img src="/mysite/images/two/img-4.jpg" />
</div>
```

So, now I've two buttons. How can I hide all images of two folder when `one` is clicked and hide all images of one folder when `two` is clicked?

I was just using `$('img[src*="one"]').hide();`

Comment: Please post the code you have written to attempt this yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use *=

```
$('#two').on('click', function () {
    $('img[src*="/one/"]').hide();
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/4rq5s/)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Ah true, will add that

Answer (score 0):

Try using [attribute contains selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/)

```
$("src*='images/two/'").hide();

$("src*='images/one/'").hide();
```